# Error when loading tensorflow model in google colab?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to load SkimLit model that were already trained. My code:

```
!wget https://storage.googleapis.com/ztm_tf_course/skimlit/skimlit_tribrid_model.zip
!mkdir skimlit_gs_model
!unzip skimlit_tribrid_model.zip -d skimlit_gs_model

model_path = "/content/skimlit_gs_model/skimlit_tribrid_model/"
loaded_model=tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path)
loaded_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                         optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                         metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This code didnt give me any error when running on VSC but in google colab it gives me error:

```
AssertionError: Found 1 Python objects that were not bound to checkpointed values, likely due to changes in the Python program. Showing 1 of 1 unmatched objects: [<tensorflow.python.ops.lookup_ops.MutableHashTable object at 0x7f0726306910>]
```

I tried to load with custom objects, but it did not make any differents.

```
loaded_model=tf.keras.models.load_model(model_path,custom_objects={"TextVectorization": TextVectorization,"KerasLayer": hub.KerasLayer})
```

Can someone help me point out what's happening?

Comment: Could you please try with " tf.saved_model.load" this will not throw an error, please confirm

Comment: I am able to load the model tf.saved_model.load. Can you let us know from your end?

Comment: Yes, I try it with tf.saved_model.load and it works!
but the model now is an _UserObject and I have to wrap it in a keras model, you for whom have the same problem as me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62350538/tf2-2-loading-a-saved-model-from-tensorflow-hub-failed-with-attributeerror

Thanks @TFer